# Jenkins Blue Ocean Plugin to show the node the stage ran on

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

Right now, i have no idea which node the stage was run on unless i create a step to execute hostname. its cumbersome

[image]

Is there way to see which node the Stage ran on?

Comment: c.f. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-47138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `${env.NODE_NAME}`, don't need to exec `hostname`.

With a scripted pipeline at least, there's no guaranteed one-to-one relationship between a node and a stage. You can actually have stages that work on multiple nodes, sequentially, or even in parallel.
So I doubt you can find a plugin that will render the pipeline in BO with that piece of information.

You could always print out (`echo`) the node name as the first step of your `stage`, so that it shows readily in the BO log at the bottom.
Possibly, you could even extend the `stage` command with a wrapper dsl command `myStage` that prints that out first thing as well (so DRY).
That custom dsl command could also set (prefix or suffix) your stage name with the node name.

Comment: I appreciate the complexity but in the case where there is a `node` step _within_ a `stage` it would help if the same _"Running on <agentname> in <workspace>"_ text were shown in the list of steps in the Blue Ocean UI, as it is in the classic UI under 'Pipeline Steps' (/flowGraphTable/) once you find and click through to the console output of the node step ("Allocate node : Start") - currently I have to switch to classic UI, CTRL+F the list for my stage name and then click through to the console of the nested 'node' stage. In the mean time I'll be sprinkling `echo` as per your suggestion!